# I am trying to add the results of to queries together

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a single query to display the results of 2 queries.  The headings are identical but I just cant seem to figure this out.  Here is what I have written:

```
    SELECT ut.question_id, ut.question, ut.response_value, ut.response_text, SUM(ut.total)
FROM 
((SELECT survey_questions.id AS 'question_id', survey_questions.question, (survey_responses.sort_order+1) AS 'response_value', 
survey_responses.response AS 'response_text', COUNT(survey_responses.response) AS 'total' 
FROM voters, group_precincts, voters_surveys, survey_questions, survey_responses  
WHERE survey_questions.survey_id = 1 
AND voters.id=voters_surveys.voter_id 
AND voters.precinct = group_precincts.precincts 
AND group_precincts.group_id IN (0) 
AND voters_surveys.question_id = survey_questions.id 
AND voters_surveys.response_id = survey_responses.id 
AND voters_surveys.timestamp BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-01 00:00:00') AS 'T'

UNION ALL

(SELECT survey_questions.id AS 'question_id', survey_questions.question, (survey_responses.sort_order+1) AS 'response_value', 
survey_responses.response AS 'response_text', COUNT(voters_surveys_responses.response_id) AS 'total' 
FROM groups, `voters_surveys_responses`, survey_questions, survey_responses  
WHERE `voters_surveys_responses`.question_id = survey_questions.id 
AND `voters_surveys_responses`.response_id = survey_responses.id 
AND `voters_surveys_responses`.timestamp BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-01 00:00:00' 
AND survey_questions.survey_id = 1  
AND groups.id IN (0)) AS 'U') AS 'ut'
GROUP BY ut.question_id, ut.response_value;
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue ?

Comment: `The headings are identical but I just cant seem to figure this out.` is not very helpful. Telling us what you have tried and why it doesn't work is helpful. No one is going to willingly read through all that code and picking up a missing comma or something. You need to tell us what you tried and which parts work and which part doesn't

Comment: I am getting an error message.  I have been looking through past posts and they stated that I had to have an alias for each select query.  I am not sure if I did that correctly though. I am trying to take the value of one column in one query and add it with the value of same column in another query but need to keep it grouped by the other columns

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, near the UNION ALL. I don't think you can use `AS 'T'` and `AS 'U'` where you added them. You are not using these nicknames, so try removing them and re-running.

Another possible problem is that you are grouping by `question_id` and `response_value` but also selecting `question`. You will probably only be able to select fields that you group by, or perform an aggregate function on (like how you apply `SUM()` to `total`.

A possible solution is to add `question` to the GROUP BY.

Comment: Here is the error message:Query: select ut.question_id, ut.question, ut.response_value, ut.response_text, sum(ut.total) from ((sELECT survey_questions.id AS 'que...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''T'

union ALL

(SELECT survey_questions.id AS 'question_id', survey_questio' at line 12

Comment: I tried adding all the selected fields, except the sum(total) and that did not help.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks for the reply